# "new" Solidity keyword deploying the "Factory" contract again instead of "MyContract"

Tags: solidity, remix, ganache

I have been trying to develop a parent contract that will deploy other contracts on request with different parameters. I came across the "new" keyword which seemed like a perfect choice.

But when I am trying to deploy the parent contract and deploy child contracts from it, the same parent is getting deployed again.

I am writing the contract on remix and using Ganache.

The code for the contract is as below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract Factory {
    address[] public newContracts;

    function createContract (string memory name) public{
        address newContract = address(new MyContract(name));
        newContracts.push(newContract);
    } 
}

contract MyContract {
    string public Name;

    constructor (string memory name) public {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure!!, i tested it and it does not deploy the factory contract :/.

How are you deploying the child contract?

[image]